# Bootstrap modal with content cant be opened twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Just starting out so please bear with me :)

I have searched all over this site for answers but I could not find one that matched my problem.

I'm trying to open a bootstrap modal and get some content for it using the jQuery ajax form plugin. It works and the content is showed in the modal, however, when I close the modal and open it again, the screen just flickers and gets grey (backdrop opens) and then it goes back.

If I reload the site and try again, it works until I try to open the same modal again. 
But if I skip loading content to the modal it opens / closes fine as many times as I want. So I think it has something to do with the old content being there when opening it again. Sometimes the content changes so I need to wipe the old ones from the modal div, but I cant seem to get it to work.

Standard modal div:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-custom.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Lukk</button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="something" style="display:none;">
        </div>          
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Button used to open the modal:

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary push" id="1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Button</button>
```

And finally, the script to fill the modal with content:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.push').click(function(){
      var id = $(this).attr('id');
      $.ajax({
         type : 'post',
         url : 'target.php', 
         data :  {'id': id}, 

         success : function(r)
        {     
          //show modal
          $('#myModal').modal('show') 
          $('.something').show().html(r); //Show the content in the modal div            

       } //Success push
    });//.ajax

}); //push

   //Trying to close modal and delete content
   $("#myModal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
      $('#myModal').removeData('bs.modal')
      $(this).data('bs.modal', null);
    }); //myModal hidden

});//document ready
```

As mentioned, this works once. But upon closing the modal and opening again it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out after several(!) hours and it turns out to be a rookie mistake. 
Posting it here in case anyone else has the same problem.

Turns out the HTML the ajax-post returns also contained all the script-sources:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-custom.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
```

So this was causing problems. When deleting these from the "target.php" it seems to work just fine :)